# How to use floating point numbers in x86-64 assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, intel, fpu

I'm struggling with some x86-64 assembly, and floating point numbers are giving me a headache. For instance, when I run this code :

```
section .data
     omega:  dq 2.0
     omega2: dq 3.0

section .text
global func

func: push rbp
      mov rgp, rsp

      FINIT

      FLD qword [omega]
      FLD qword [omega2]
      FADD st0, st0

      mov rsp, rbp
      pop rbp
      ret
```

This function is called from a C code like that : `printf("%Lf \n", func() );`
Unfortunately the result is some bizarre number... I tried adding two integers using `FIADD`, and it worked fine. I dug through a ton of material already, but maybe someone here can point me to decent FPU tutorial, or share her/his experience and wisdom :)

Wrapping up the essentials:

- language: x86-64 assembler
- assembler: nasm v. 2.09.04 installed from repositories
- compiler (for C): gcc v. 4.5.2 (installed with Ubuntu)
- OS: Ubuntu 11.04 64bit on Oracle VM
- Host OS: Windows 7 SP1 64bit
- Processor: Intel i5 - 2430M 64bit (checked twice :D )
- Problem: FPU can't add two numbers :(

Just in case : in the end i hope to use `FSINCOS` and other fancy FPU instructions, but seeing as even simple addition fails...

Thanks all in advance!

Comment: One way to figure out the intricacies is to compile some simple C code, and look at the resulting machine code with a disassembler.

Comment: Well, it seems that it used SSE instruction set. Maybe I will try this approach tomorrow.

Comment: You don't use the legacy FPU in x86_64. At least you shouldn't. Better use the scalar SSE instructions.

Comment: why don't use SSE/SSE2, it's much faster and you don't get into trouble like the stack problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so in the end it turned out that my problems were related to the fact, that FPU registers are organized as a stack, and i didn't pay enough attention to it which resulted in garbage and unwanted leftovers. Switching from "standard" to "pop" versions of instructions helped!

Anyway - thanks to all who bothered to read, it is much appreciated! :)

If anyone is interested - I was doing a class assignment where I had to compute motion of one planet from the view of another (geocentric model) in assembly.  [The final result translated to processing can be viewed here.](http://home.elka.pw.edu.pl/~plopusin/arko/)

Answer (score 0):

The `L` qualifier to printf %f makes that argument a `long double` (80-bit float), which is not the assembly data type.  Remove the `L` and it will default to a `double` (64-bit float) which is what you are computing.

Also, it should be

```
  FADD st1, st0
```

to add the two numbers together.  Otherwise it will double the second value.

Comment: Well, the problem still stands.

Comment: @Losiowaty: Does the `C` code have a declaration for `func()`?

Comment: It does, otherwise I would get a linker error during compilation.
And you are right with the addition formula, but still, it doesn't matter what i try to add/sub/div/mul.

Comment: @Losiowaty:  What is the declaration?  Especially the return type.

Comment: I tried all of them : float, double, long double, but it goes like this: `extern double func();`

Comment: @Losiowaty: `double func(void);` is the most correct.  What C compiler is it?  You may have to look for a compiler option to return floating point values in the FPU.